# Header is repeating in IE8 after using HTML5

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I am using HTML5 and CSS3 in my project. To Work in IE8, I am importing famous html5.js downloaded from code.google.com.

But what I am facing is, my main header is repeating twice down side while it is looking perfect in Chrome and Firefox.

What is going on wrong here?

CSS:

```
header#US_header {
    background-image:url('/images//US_header.png');
    width:910px;
    height:82px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0;
}
```

JSP:

```
<header id="US_header">
```

Comment: this has non to do with your question but you have two slashes in the image path

Comment: tha was by mistake.. i've added here while posting.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

use `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Comment: I am not getting single image. It is repeating twice. Is there any problem related to html5.js..?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do that... my code is so complex. it has so many JS, JSPS.. In JSPS i am adding... I simply cant undersatnd , Y it is happening.. If I remove html5.js, then Header image is not coming because of <header> tags. But after adding, it is recognizing but where header image is coming twice. I am not getting..